# Google Sites: code block - how to disable wrapping

Tags: google-sites, code

I'm using Google Sites to host the wiki-like website.

I noticed that code blocks have text wrapped in them. Instead, I would like to have the code non-wrapped and with horizontal scrollbar when needed. Has anyone accomplished this?

I would like to do this without Html-markup editing of each post that contains a code block.

Answer (score 1):

You can accompish this by editing the CSS styling of the block quote so there's no need to remove the quote block as this would be bad for SEO purposes.

Typical Example of a Scroll-bar within Block Quote:

```
blockquote { 
    width:600px; 
    max-height:150px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

I made a online demo so you can take a look of it in action, here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ8Mp/1/).

If you still want to proceed without doing `blockquote` then you can use a div element such as: `<div class="quote"> </div>` and just copy the styling options from the `blockquote`

To edit this in Google sites you use [Insert Custom, HTML, JavaScript, CSS](http://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en).

Comment: Where (in the Google Sites control panel) can I write this style block?

Comment: Updated answer with a link to the required information,.

Comment: This will require modifying all the pages one-by-one. As stated in my question, I would like to avoid this approach. Instead, I want to write this block once (question is - where?) and have it applied to all the pages. Thanks though!

Comment: Google sites has limitations and most styling has to be on the page, if you want the flexibility of a real host and web design.. get a real host and use a open source wiki or equal with this flexibility. The method I provided means you don't need to individual edit each styling of each blockquote.

Comment: But I need to do it once on each page right? this is definitely useful, but not exactly an answer. +1